# Regular expression for whether a string can be made from a set of letters

Tags: sql, regex, expression

I'm in the process of making a Scrabble helper, where you can enter letters and see which words can be made from them. I have a MySQL table containing all of the words but I'm failing on retrieving them. Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT
    word
FROM
    dictionary
WHERE
    word REGEXP '^[example]*$'
```

but this doesn't work in that it will return words that contain more than one `a`, for example. Is there any way I can achieve this?

(I'm also open to any methods that don't use regular expressions, although it seems as though regular expressions would be the best way to do this).

Comment: I'm thinking a stored procedure that sorts the characters in order.  You could keep a second column on the db for all the words so the sorted strings are precomputed.  Then you call the stored procedure to sort your "tiles" and join to the "sorted" column.

Comment: Expanding on Derek's point - the easiest way to determine whether two arrays are equal, ignoring order, is to sort both and check. All you need to do is sort the letters in the word and sort the letters in your hard. It's then a simple matter of looping. This should be easily doable in a stored procedure.

Comment: @Derek That would work fine for just anagrams, but I also want it to return words not the same length. For example, "dog" should return not only "god", but "do" and "go". Unfortunately that method wouldn't do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's *a* solution; there's surely room for optimization:

```
DECLARE @Word  VARCHAR(8) = 'Stack'
DECLARE @Avail VARCHAR(8) = 'ACKST'

DECLARE @Letters TABLE
    (
    Letter  CHAR(1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NumNeeded   INT NOT NULL,
    NumAvailable    INT NOT NULL
    )
INSERT INTO @Letters (Letter, NumNeeded, NumAvailable)
    SELECT
        R.Letter, R.NumNeeded, COALESCE(A.NumAvailable, 0) AS NumAvailable
    FROM
            (
            SELECT
                Letter, COUNT(*) AS NumNeeded
            FROM
                (
                SELECT UPPER(SUBSTRING(@Word, N.Number, 1)) AS Letter
                FROM Numbers AS N
                WHERE N.Number BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(@Word)
                ) AS X
            GROUP BY
                Letter
            ) AS R
        LEFT JOIN
            (
            SELECT
                Letter, COUNT(*) AS NumAvailable
            FROM
                (
                SELECT UPPER(SUBSTRING(@Avail, N.Number, 1)) AS Letter
                FROM Numbers AS N
                WHERE N.Number BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(@Word)
                ) AS X
            GROUP BY
                Letter
            ) AS A ON R.Letter = A.Letter

SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @Letters WHERE NumNeeded > NumAvailable) THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS OK
```

Note that you'll need a Numbers table.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just stick with your Regex.

Treat your database return values as being "possible" matches.

Then in your business logic (not sure what programming language you are using) you loop through all possible matches and do some string manipulation to determine which matches are "valid" matches.